# selenium webdriver ruby warning messages in log

Tags: selenium, rspec, selenium-webdriver

I recorded some tests using the ide and then exported them to ruby/rspec. When I run them they work, but I get lots of warnings. Can you tell me how to get rid of this warning?

```
 net/http: warning: Content-Type did not set; using application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

I get this every time I try to call driver find element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still have this issue in 2018 for some Selenium commands. A workaround:

```
module Selenium
    module WebDriver
        module Remote
            module Http
                class Common
                    ORIGINAL_DEFAULT_HEADERS = DEFAULT_HEADERS
                    remove_const :DEFAULT_HEADERS
                    DEFAULT_HEADERS = ORIGINAL_DEFAULT_HEADERS.merge( 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ).freeze
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: FYI, I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/5659) to fix this issue.